# Where is the versions-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

I cant find it anywhere: the website doesn't point to any repository and the guessed http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/mojo folder is empty.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the [official maven website](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) points exactly to that location to download the codehaus' plugins... why, oh, why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its in the **central** "default" maven repo
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/versions-maven-plugin/1.2/

Answer (score 0):

the repository for version 1.2 is located [here](https://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/tags/versions-maven-plugin-1.2/) and the trunk is [here](https://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/trunk/mojo/versions-maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

The links to source repository are [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/source-repository.html). As for the plugin itself, it is present in maven central [repo](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/versions-maven-plugin/)